# Using extensions for protocol conformance when superclass also conforms

Tags: swift

In Swift, a general best practice has come about to place protocol conformance for a class into a separate extension. This helps separate out code into logical sections:

```
class SuperClass: UIViewController {
...
}

extension SuperClass: UITableViewDelegate {
...
}
```

However, in an app I am currently working on, a base superclass and subclass both need to provide methods for `UITableViewDelegate`.

To logically separate the code, one would think to do:

```
class Subclass: SuperClass {
...
}

extension Subclass: UITableViewDelegate {
...
}
```

However, Swift complains that the class already conforms to the protocol. At the moment, I have simply removed the `: UITableViewDelegate` part of the extension.

This seems to be a bit of a caveat of using this best practice. Are there any better ways of organising code in this case?

Comment: why dont you use comments ?

Comment: I do, but I'd still prefer a practice that is universal. Right now I have:

// MARK:
// MARK: UITableViewDelegate
// This extension does not conform to UITableViewDelegate because the superclass does. Unfortunately the paradigm of having protocol conformance in extensions does not work well with superclass protocol conformance. I've decided to still place it in an extension for conformity with the rest of the application and to section off delegate code.

Comment: In general I prefer not to subclass `UIViewControllers`. I prefer them to be final classes. Any code that is needed by more than one VC shouldn't be in the body of a VC anyway. But this is more an opinion than a rule. Look up Massive ViewController and how to avoid it without subclassing.

Comment: I'd prefer that too. The Protocol-oriented programming WWDC talk gave me hope of using protocols, but I'm unsure of how I'd go about doing a lot of the tasks I'd want to abstract out. In this case, all of my VC's are custom table view controllers (with TPKeyboardAvoiding). When the tableview scrolls, it creates a background behind the status bar. This happens in 90% of my view controllers.

Comment: Something like TPKeyboardAvoiding can be implemented as a protocol itself. Then you wouldn't need to subclass to get the behaviour you want/need